# onchange apartir de un datalist

Tags: ajax, datalist

Quiero que a partir de mi datalist al cambiar me traiga el código desde mi base de datos y lo agrege automáticamente en el input

```
//Este en mi html
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #DEDFD6;">
        <br>
        <center><img src="imagenes/logohtc.png" width="100" height="80" align="center"></center><br>   
        <center>
            <form action=testp1.php method="POST" id="form">
                <table style="font-family: monospace;" border="0">
                    <tr class="Descripcion">
                        <td>Municipio:</td>
                        <td><input list="listaMunicipio" placeholder="Municipio" required="required" name="Municipio"/><datalist id="listaMunicipio">
                            <option value="25 de Mayo"/>
                            <option value="9 de Julio"/>
                            <option value="Adolfo Alsina"/>
                            <option value="Trenque Lauquen"/>
                            <option value="Tres Arroyos"/>
                            <option value="Tres de Febrero"/>
                            <option value="Tres Lomas"/>
                            <option value="Vicente Lopez"/>
                            <option value="Villa Gesell"/>
                            <option value="Villarino"/>
                            <option value="Zarate"/>
                        </datalist>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="Descripcion">
                    <td>Codigo Municipio:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCodMun"  id="txtCodMun" minlength= "5"maxlength="5" size="9" required="required" /></td>
                    <tr class="Descripcion">
                        <td>Año: </td>

                        <td><input type="text" name="txtAnio" id="txtAnio" minlength="4 "maxlength="4" size="4" required="required"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </center>
            </table>   <br>
            <input type="submit" name="btnLlamar" id="btnLlamar" value="Cargar Municipio"/>
            <h4 style="text-align: right;"><a href="Eleccion.php">Volver</a> </h4>
    </body>
    </html>
```

creo que mi problema esta en como defino las variables pero no estoy muy seguro es la segunda vez que uso Ajax

```
//El ajax donde hace el onchange llamando al cambio de la lista 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#listaMunicipio').onchange(function){

            muni=$('#listaMunicipio').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"php/codigoauto.php",
                data:{muni:muni},
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){
                        $('#txtCodMun').value($mmuni);
                    }else{
                        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

nose si estoy recibiendo y enviando bien las variables
    //y este es el php que llama la funcion

```
            $munici=$_POST['muni'];


            $sql= "SELECT Codigo from municipiozona where Municipio =".$munici;
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            $fila=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $mmuni=$fila[0];
    ?>
```

Comment: Primero deberias de en el ajax poner el `error`, asi sabrias concretamente que tipo de error estas recibiendo (404, 400, 500, etc) segundo asegurarte que si este llegando al php de destino, luego validar si llega un dato y en cualquiera de los dos caso imprimier algo, ya que ahi no estas devolviendo ningun valor

Comment: el alerty.error esta puesto pero no sale ningun error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira tenias error en el cuenstiones de sintaxis, ya que faltaban un parentesis interno, y la lofica estaba algo mal, he editado tu codigo y lo he dejado funcional, pruebalo y me cuentas...

Código JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                                //aqui faltaba parentesis de apertura funcion anonina
    $('#listaMunicipio').onchange(function(){
        muni =$('#listaMunicipio').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"php/codigoauto.php",
            data:{muni:muni},
            success:function(r){
               //validas que no llegue error 
                if(r!='Error'){
                                  //asignas el valor que llego
                    $('#txtCodMun').value($r);
                }else{
                     //aqui mostrar un alert si no enviaste los datos
                    alertify.error("Respuesta del controlador: No se recibieron los datos necesarios");
                }
            },//aqui capturas si hubo error en la peticion
            error: function(response){
                console.log('error:', response);
            }
        });
    //aqui parentesis de cierre del onchange
    })
});
```

Código php...

```
$resultado='';
if (isset($_POST['muni']) && !empty($_POST['muni']) ) {// validamos que haya llegado el dato para la consulta
  $munici=$_POST['muni'];

  $sql= "SELECT Codigo from municipiozona where Municipio =".$munici;
  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  $fila=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $resultado = $fila[0];// aqui devolveremos el codigo del municipio
}
else{
  $resultado='Error';//si no llego el dato mandamos error
}
//siempre imprime algun resultado
echo $resultado;
```

NOTA: es importante saber que las peticiones ajax siempre deben retornar un valor, y ese valor lo retorna con una `echo` o `var_dum` en variables o en paquete de JSON

Comment: es casi la solucion, hay un detalle que no me habia dado cuenta y es que hay q asigarle un id diferente al input id=listamunicipio2 por ejemplo y cambiarlo tambien en el <script> porque sino no se actualiza ya que el id actual es el del datalist y no el del input. pero tu solucion si resulto!! muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra mucho haberte ayudado y mas aun que termines de solucionarlo... exitos